# SpringSource Tool Suite (STS) installed via the update site is not working

Tags: eclipse, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have managed to install STS into eclipse via one of the update sites. However, I can't find a single indication of STS in eclipse. As suggested by a install guide when I go to In Window > Open perspetive> Other... there is no spring option. However, Spring IDE is registered in Installed software section, which means installation was successful.

Any idea what could be a problem?

Comment: @DaveNewton enabled? So far I haven't found enable/Disable plugin option in eclipse. btw, there is no plugin entry for STS, it can only be found under Installed Software

Comment: Need more information.  Which version of Eclipse did you start with?  Which update site did you use?  Which features did you choose?  Any errors in error log (Window -> Show view -> other -> error log)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to install STS from its installer available on Spring site. Because installing sts via update site is not successful everytime. There may be the case of some error while installing from the update site.

Here is the link to download the installer file and then install the complete sts.
First you will be asked to fill some detail before you'll be redirected to the download page. Its very simple.

[Download STS here](http://www.springsource.org/springsource-tool-suite-download)

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.